# multi auth not working in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, multi-tenant

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I need multiple login in my project so I am trying **Kbwebs\MultiAuth** and **Sarav\Multiauth** for multi auth, both are worked with **user model** model but unfortunately when I use **TenderApplicant** model **Auth::attempt** return false every time.

This is my code:

**app.php**

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Sarav\Multiauth\MultiauthServiceProvider::class,
    ...
```

**auth.php**

```
return [
'multi' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'sa_users',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Models\TenderApplicant::class,
        'table'  => 'tender_applicant',
    ],
],
'password' => [
    'email'  => 'emails.password',
    'table'  => 'sa_password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
],

];
```

**AuthController.php**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

public function userAuth(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required','password' => 'required']);

    $email      = $request->input('email');
    $password   = $request->input('password');
    var_dump(Auth::attempt("user", ['email' => 'awal.ashu@gmail.com', 'password' => '123456']));
}
```

return false for user but admin worked perfected.

**TenderApplicant.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class TenderApplicant extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table      = 'tender_applicant';
    protected $primaryKey = 'TE_APP_ID';
    const CREATED_AT      = 'CREATED_AT';
    const UPDATED_AT      = 'UPDATED_AT';

    protected $fillable = [
                        'TENDER_ID', 
                        'SCHEDULE_ID', 
                        'PR_DETAIL_ID', 
                        'NID', 
                        'PR_CATEGORY', 
                        'PR_TYPE', 
                        'APPLICANT_NAME',
                        'EMAIL',  
                        'APPLICANT_PHONE', 
                        'PASSWORD', 
                        'HOLDING_NO', 
                        'IS_TE_SC_BOUGHT', 
                        'TE_SC_AMOUNT', 
                        'TE_SC_DATE', 
                        'SPOUSE_NAME', 
                        'BID_AMOUNT',
                        'BG_AMOUNT', 
                        'BG_AMOUNT_TEXT',
                        'BANK_ID',
                        'B_DRAFT_NO', 
                        'B_DRAFT_DATE', 
                        'B_DRAFT_ATTACHMENT', 
                        'IS_SELECTED', 
                        'IS_ACTIVE', 
                        'CREATED_BY', 
                        'UPDATED_BY'
                    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['TE_APP_ID'];

    /**
     * Password need to be all time encrypted.
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['PASSWORD'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us here the row from users table?

Comment: This is the user table details:
protected $table = 'sa_users'; protected $primaryKey = 'USER_ID'; const CREATED_AT = 'CREATED_AT'; const UPDATED_AT = 'UPDATED_AT'; protected $fillable = [  'USER_TYPE',  'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'FULL_NAME',  'GENDER', 'USERNAME', 'EMAIL', 'PASSWORD',  'MOBILE_NO', 'IS_ACTIVE', 'CREATED_BY', 'UPDATED_BY'];

Comment: I mean, did you check if password hash is right (Auth::hash()) and if user is present in the sa_users table

Comment: Yeah user present in sa_users table and `class 'Sarav\Multiauth\Guard' does not have a method 'hash'`
That's not my problem, when I use User model it worked but I am unable to loging using TenderApplicant model. I have no idea where is the error. All I just got return false from Auth::attempt(); Even user present in tender_applicant table and password is correct

Comment: I would open issue on Git repo. And let us know if you find the solution

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In what Git repo would you like to open an issue? Do you have any suggestion that may help me out of the problem?

Comment: I saw you found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Laravel excepts you to keep password field as "password". In case you change(you have kept as PASSWORD), you have to inform Laravel about your password field change.

Please add the following code to your TenderApplicant.php file and check

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->PASSWORD;
}
```

And then try accessing like the following,

```
Auth::attempt('admin', ['EMAIL' => 'youremail@gmail.com', 'password' => 'your_password']);
```

NOTE : You don't have to change your **password** as **PASSWORD** in here, because we have defined our method in model.

1. When you try attempting Auth::attempt(), laravel will run following query

   SELECT * FROM "your_auth_table" WHERE email = "given_email" LIMIT 1
2. Then with the obtained result, laravel will take password field from the obtained result which will be hash.
3. Then it will call getAuthPassword() method from model and get the password field you have provided. By default it will be "password". Now with php function

   password_verify
   , laravel will verify your hash password with user given plain text and initiate user session

For more information you can check this blog.

http://blog.sarav.co/laravel-password-management-mechanism/

Comment: Finally it worked :), thank you @Saravanan Sampathkumar.

Comment: After successfully login, `Auth::user() return NULL`. Is there anything that I missed @Saravanan Sampathkumar?

Comment: Yes. For admin login, you will have to call like Auth::user('admin') :)

Comment: Okay, but for admin `Auth::user() return` all data. why user can't? Event I can't use `Authenticate` Middleware :(